# Removing rows from a dataframe based on a large list

Tags: r

I have a long list of values which I want to use as indexing to remove rows from another data frame which contains this values at a specific column.

A simple examle to make it is

```
X <- data.frame(Variable1=c(11,14,12,15),Variable2=c(2,3,1,4))
X[X$Variable1!=11 & X$Variable1!=12, ]
```

but is there any efficient way to use the dataframe with the values I have which is the list I want to use in the second dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` for creating a logical index based on multiple values.

```
X[!(X$Variable1 %in% c(11, 12)),]
```

---

If we are using `data.table` an option would be to `set` the `key` and then negate the values

```
library(data.table)
setDT(X, key = "Variable1")[!.(c(11,12))]
#     Variable1 Variable2
#1:        14         3
#2:        15         4
```

Or we use `on` as @David Arenburg commented

```
setDT(X)[!.(11:12), on = "Variable1"]
```

Comment: if c is a data frame (let's say it is df2) is it right to use `X[!Variable1 %in% df2,]` ?

Comment: @Jake Sorry, I meant `X$Variable1`

Comment: @Jake It does work for me `df2 <- data.frame(group_1 = c(11, 12));setDT(X)[!.(df2$group_1), on = "Variable1"]
#   Variable1 Variable2
1:        14         3
2:        15         4`  I am using `data.table_1.9.7`

Comment: than you I have an older version of data.table. now it works